# $routeProvider - injecting controller dependencies depending on URL

Tags: javascript, dependency-injection, angularjs

Consider the code:

```
var app = angular.module("app", [], function($routeProvider) {
  $routeProvider
    .when("/page1", { controller: "MyController" })
    .when("/page2", { controller: "MyController" })
    .when("/page3", { controller: "MyController" });
});

app.factory("StrategyOne", function() {...});
app.factory("StrategyTwo", function() {...});
app.factory("StrategyThree", function() {...});

app.controller("MyController", function(Strategy, $scope) {...});
```

Depending on URL, I want either `StrategyOne`, or `StrategyTwo`, or `StrategyThree` to be injected, when constructing `MyController`. A pseudo-code to illustrate the idea:

```
var app = angular.module("app", [], function($routeProvider) {
  $routeProvider
    .when("/page1", { controller: "MyController", Strategy: "StrategyOne" })
    .when("/page2", { controller: "MyController", Strategy: "StrategyTwo" })
    .when("/page3", { controller: "MyController", Strategy: "StrategyThree" });
});
```

Any change I can achieve something like this with AngularJS?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Yes! AngularJS can handle this pretty easily thnx to the `resolve` property of a route definition (more info [here](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24routeProvider)).

So, basically you could write something like:

```
var app = angular.module("app", [], function($routeProvider) {
  $routeProvider
    .when("/page1", { controller: "MyController", resolve: {Strategy: "StrategyOne"}})
    .when("/page2", { controller: "MyController", resolve: {Strategy: "StrategyTwo"}})
    .when("/page3", { controller: "MyController", resolve: {Strategy: "StrategyThree"}});
});
```

to have the proper strategy injected into your controller! AngularJS DI at its best!

There is a very good video tutorial dealing with the `resolve` topics, you might find it interesting: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=P6KITGRQujQ&list=UUKW92i7iQFuNILqQOUOCrFw&index=4&feature=plcp

Comment: OMG, I've been sure it's possible, but I haven't been expecting it's _that_ easy. Thanks! :-)

Comment: Does this still work? I'm running into an issue stated [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/angular/QtO8QoxSjYw/SWxea0tOBGYJ)  Where my factory is only called once; and not each time the route should be resolved.

Comment: @Lucas This is probably because factories are singletons and are only ever called once! What happens is that the factory is injected into your controller (no method is called on it), leaving your controller tocall whatever it likes against your it e.g. in your controller `StrategyOne.getContent()`